# Java FX JAR File can not find SQL Server Driver

Tags: sql-server, javafx, jdbc, jar, executable-jar

I fought for 8 hours yesterday getting my Java FX (11) Standalone JAR to work at all. I finally did, and now when I run it via `java -jar myjar.jar` (with path info for fx components), it at least "works" inasmuch as I can see my "own application's" error messages and message boxes lol.

This app needs to connect to SQL Server. It works FINE in IDE (IntelliJ). For JAR, I did not include the SQL Server driver as it is signed. No big deal - figure I'd just deploy it too and put it in the path. However, the JAR file can not "see" the driver (or the class - not sure) when run. Here is the info:

SQL Server driver is `mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar`

My connection Code is:
`connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString);` and `connectString = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydatabase;userName=myuser;password=mypword"`

Again - this WORKS FINE in IDE. However, run from jar, it gets "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydatabase;userName=myuser;password=mypword"

I have put the `mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar` into the same directory as the jar. I have included it in the MANIFEST.MF with `Class-Path: mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar` and also tried it in a "lib" subdirectory from the jar file with `Class-Path: /lib`. Nothing Works! I just keep getting the "no suitable driver" error. The full manifest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: /lib
Main-Class: com.product.Launcher
```

Here is the full call from command line that actually launches the app: `java --module-path C:/Users/KMatson/Documents/JetBrains/openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics -jar myjar.jar` This does run the app, but as soon as app tries to connect to SQL, I get the error.

Also tried the old-style `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` to no avail even thought it should not be necessary, and isn't needed run from IDE.

This is driving me crazy and has taken WAY more time than it should. I'm new to all this, and hope it is something simple I am overlooking or unaware of. Any help MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Your application is modular, so it doesn't use the classpath.

Comment: OK - so how do I get it to "see" and use the SQL Server driver? I'm still unclear about the whole "modular" thing.

Comment: sorry @MarkRotteveel - meant to tag you for my follow-up question above.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really used modules yet beyond basic toy applications, so I can't really help you. I think you need to add it to the module path and maybe do something extra.

Answer (score 0):

OK - here is the (intermediate) answer that worked for me. Apparently, having the "--module path" declaration in the cmd line was overriding the Class-path in the MANIFEST somehow. Either that or something was - dunno - didn't think i had a "modular" project. I'm not building from Maven, and module-info is not active.

Anyway - I simply put the driver jar in the "module path" I use from cmd, and it worked. I'm now trying to figure out how to make this thing "double clickable" so i don't have to issue from cmd line or use a batch file.